# SSIS stuck on SP validation

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a complex process running from SSIS with several SPs.
The process has been working well for quite some time and now I'm mainly working on correcting the logic.

This afternoon the process stopped working. I didn't receive any errors since the process didn't crash, it's just "stuck" on the validation. The last line in the output window is: `SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning`.

The part that it's validating is an SQL SP that I've adjusted today. The SP itself runs fine when I execute it from SSMS.

Can someone give me an idea why it seems to be validating forever?

---

**EDIT**

After running the same process with a different set of data, I found that it runs without any problems. I didn't change any of the packages, just the data set.

Could something in the data cause the validation to to hang?

Comment: The query could be blocked by another process. The proc could be accessing a block with that data that has an infinite loop in it. The possibilities are near endless since we nothing more concrete than: the proc code was changed and the package might sit in the Validation phase for an extended period of time. What's the proc look like, what's your underlying data model, what's the source data look like when it works vs when it doesn't work, etc, etc

Comment: Next time it occurs take a look at the process in SQL Server Management Studio and see if you can identify a hung process which is related to that stored procedure - that's the next level of troubleshooting.